# How to find $ K_{3,3}$ or $ K_{5}$ in graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hey I am supposed to decide if the following graph is a planar graph.
[image]

I know that necessary and sufficient condition for the graph not to be planar, is to find $ K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$. But somehow I am lost and I do not know, how to do it.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This graph is not planar.

By contracting the edges $(a,b),(j,a),(e,f),(f,g)$
You get $K_{3,3}$ as a minor, where $A:= \{a,d,h\}, B:=\{c,f,i\}$ is a partition.

Comment: But how should I decide, how to divide vertrices?

Comment: Are you asking how this should generally be done? Hopcroft and Tarjan gave an algorithm to solve this question in linear time. It's quite complicated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing

Comment: I am asking why you pick for A:={a,d,h} this concrete vertices, why not some others?

Comment: Basically a guess... someone answer that it is planar (was deleted) and his "proof" did not address those vertices. Another intuition here, is the graph cannot contain $K_5$ as a minor or subdivision, so you should look for $K_{3,3}$, and you should pick vertices with degree at least 3.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you form cliques $A=(abj)$ and $F=(feg)$, then you can see that the following partition: $Adh,Fci$ is complete.

In other words, you can redraw it like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much